# Passing the value using checkbox with html and php

Tags: php, html

I have two forms

a) post.php
b) edit.php

I am using the checkbox in both the form to set the binary value (0 and 1) to set the status for approve.

to process the value from the checkbox in the post.php I am using the code which checks and assume that if the checkbox is checked then the value will be 1 other wise it is 0 by default

```
if (isset($_POST['ad_approve'])) $ad_approve  = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ad_approve'])));
        else { $ad_approve = 0; }
```

Now in the edit.php form I retrieve the data from the database and set the checkbox accordingly . if the approve has the value 1 then it is checked by default . look onto the following code

```
<input name="ad_approve" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if($approve==1) echo 'checked="checked"';?> />
```

in the above code I cannot apply the same logic to catch the value from ad_approve i.e(by checking isset()) because if the value is 1 by default and if I try unchecking the checkbox then automatically the program assume that the value is set because it has been changed from checked to unchecked. now in the edit.php how do I again process the value from it such that if the checkbox is checked hold the value as 1 otherwise 0, ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be honest your question does not make a whole lot of sense but I can understand that you wish to check if check boxes are actually set.

firstly you don't need a value attribute on a check box because its the browser that decide what value if any to send via the GP headers.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

> Checkboxes (and radio buttons) are
>   on/off switches that may be toggled by
>   the user. A switch is "on" when the
>   control element's checked attribute is
>   set. When a form is submitted, only
>   "on" checkbox controls can become
>   successful.

So basically if a checkbox is not selected then the entity will not be sent via the headers, there for `isset()` would be a perfectly usable check.

The way your using real escape is totally wrong, you should never user real escape for html, DATABASE ONLY.

Take this code for example

```
if(isset($_POST['some_check']))
{
    echo $_POST['some_check']; //on
}else
{
    echo 'some_check has not been checked';
}
```

Your code:

```
if (isset($_POST['ad_approve'])) $ad_approve  = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ad_approve'])));
        else { $ad_approve = 0; }
```

Can you give me a good excuse why your using `htmlspecialchars`,`strip_tags` and `mysql_real_escape_string` on an entity that can be done like so:

```
$ad_approve = isset($_POST['ad_approve']) ? true : false;
```

for issues like this its not that hard to refer to the documentation to get a better understand of what exactly is being sent from the browser.

if you wish to add values to to the checkboxes that you would do this with hidden fields, example follows.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_box" />
<input type="hidden" name="check_box_value" value="01100001" />
```

And within the php server side.

```
if(isset($_POST['check_box']))
{
    echo $_POST['check_box_value']; //01100001
}else
{
    echo 'some_check has not been checked';
}
```

by adding another html input thats hidden you can hide elements from the user and then use as data holders, the reason why you should use the exact same name but append it with `_value` is just for best practises.

---

EDIT

```
if(isset($_POST['some_check_box']))
{
    mysql_query('UPDATE profile SET receive_mail = 1');
}else
{
   mysql_query('UPDATE profile SET receive_mail = 0');
}
```

Comment: +1 for the information, if this is not the way then how do we process the value from the checkbox, because what i want is to get the binary values from the checkbox and do some operations like compare, insert and update .  and FYI i am coding for the first time, it was someone who recommended me to do it this way so only i adopted it and i am gonna correct myself rite away. thank you

Comment: Updated with a work around that would be advisable, also binary data is quite lengthy, have you thought about storing the data server side such as mysql and then using id's to track the data.

Comment: @RobertPitt that was just the demonstration of my problem not the exact code, i am using mysql to store and retrieve data, and BTW what i mean by binary data is i would store either 1 or 0 in the database not in some binary data format. :)

Comment: 1 or 0 is not binary, there intergers, `0 = 00110000` so instead of 0 you would store 00110000 within your form, unless you are mistaken about binary data, if you want a system where you can use an on/off type of checking then you would use 0 / 1 as that.

Comment: @RobertPitt i am still unaware with the logic, if i am using the checkbox just to get and store the value 0 or 1 in the database(mysql) how do i carry the value along to the database? because the user will either check it to approve or it wont not to approve. how do i achieve this task with your hidden field logic?

Comment: ive update with a final example, this is how you would store 1/0 in a database from a form.

Comment: ohhh, i got that.. thank you for correcting me, now this makes total sense... thank you for your effort to make me understand how things actually work.. :)

Comment: if the answer helped you resolve your problem then you should mark it  as accepted, as theres no other answers available.